# Deserialize Json with dynamic key C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm struggling with a Json provided by an external parter :

```
{
  "info": {
    "compa": "123"
  },
  "employees": {
    "key1": {
      "name": "dog",
      "friend": [ "cat" ]

    },
    "key2": {
      "name": "fish",
      "friend": [ "shark" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I use classes:

```
public class company
{
    public info info { get; set; }

    public employees employees { get; set; }
}

public class info
{
    public string compa { get; set; }
}

public class employees
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, employee>> employee { get; set; }
}

public class employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string friend { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize, my employee property is empty in employees class.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your C# schema. You can get rid of the `employees` class and replace it with a `Dictionary<string, employee>`. Note that it's a dictionary, not a list of dictionaries. Also note that `employee.friend` is a collection, not a string.

This works:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("json1.json");
        var company = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<company>(json);
    }
}

public class company
{
    public info info { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public class info
{
    public string compa { get; set; }
}

public class employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> friend { get; set; }
}
```